# How to fix cutting edge of php date-picker on bootstrap modal form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog

Am using a [PHP Date-picker](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php) on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) [Modal Form](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#myModal), but some design issue with it.

When [modal-form](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#myModal) appears on-click event, it didn't displayed proper date-picker design on modal form.

This is only with Mozilla Firefox v12.0, And IE-8 browsers.

**Snap:**

[image]

**Here the code snippet**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="firdiv" style="float:left; height:210px; width:260px; padding-bottom:30px;">
     <!--PHP Datepicker -->
     <?php
        include_once('calendar/tc_calendar.php');
        $curr_date = date("Y-m-d", time());
        $datepicker2=plugins_url('calendar/', __FILE__);
        $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1");
        $myCalendar->setIcon($datepicker2."images/iconCalendar.gif");
        $myCalendar->setDate(date("d"), date("m"), date("Y"));
        $myCalendar->setPath($datepicker2);
        $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2035,date('Y'));
        $myCalendar->dateAllow($curr_date, "2035-03-01", false);
        $myCalendar->setOnChange("myChanged()");
        $myCalendar->writeScript();
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

May be some inline css could help it.

If someone has knowledge about this design issue then post me or how do i fix that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i don t have this issue, can you post your form and the css?

Comment: This issue with Mozilla Firefox v12.0, And IE-8 browsers only.

Comment: True in the latest FF i have a "microscopic" date piker.